# Java non-property accessor methods that start with "get" and "set"?

Tags: java, properties, naming-conventions

In the seminal book [The Elements of Java Style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Elements_of_Java_Style) it says:

> **Follow the JavaBeans conventions for naming property accessor methods.** The JavaBeans specification establishes standard naming
>   conventions for methods that give access to the properties of a
>   JavaBean implementation. You should apply these conventions when
>   naming methods in any class, regardless of whether it implements a
>   Bean.

Our project follows this rule for `is/get/set` when creating simple (side effect free) property accessors.  But my question is this - ***is it confusing to also start other methods with get and set?***

For example, lets say I have a method that calls an external system to obtain the next number in a global sequence.  Is naming this method `getNextId()` considered bad practice?

I would think so because it makes me think that the nextId is a property of the sequence object, when really it is not.  I would think a better name would be `nextId()` or `fetchNextIdFromExternalSystem()`.

What is the best practice here?  ***Should `is/get/set` be restricted to property accessors?***

Comment: This question is not opinion based as Java has well documented best practices.  This question is a clarifying question on those.

Comment: I'm not sure if your request to reopen is valid or not. I have edited my answer with more information (now *with* sources!), this might answer any questions you have left. Either way it will also bump your post to the top and others might deem it reopen-worthy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Getters don't have to specifically map to a backing field. They only have to do what they say they do: return a value that is somehow contained within that class.

This says nothing about the way this value is stored. This can be either directly through a backing field or it can be through a lookup in a collection or it might even outsource this behind the scenes to some sort of data provider.

All this is another aspect of *encapsulation*. It shields the internal representation of a value from the outside world.

What the method does is clear to anyone who uses it: it returns the next ID. How this ID is determined is of no use for the caller and he doesn't care whether it's held as a specific field or if it requires a lookup somewhere.

You retrieve a value. The caller doesn't care how this is stored, he just wants the value. `getNextId()` is an acceptable name.

It's hard to find a straightforward official guideline but I believe it is somewhat a combination of the [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367) and the [JavaBean conventions](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch06_02.htm).

More specifically:

> Methods
>
> Methods should be **verbs**, in mixed case with the first letter lowercase, with the first letter of each internal word capitalized.
>
> `run();` `runFast();` `getBackground();`

And

> A bean defines a property p of type T if it has accessor methods that follow these patterns
>
> Getter
>
> `public T getP()`

It doesn't specify whether or not this should specifically map to one backing field, it just determines how it should be structured. By naming the method `nextID()` I see two issues:

1. The guideline of "use a verb" isn't honored
2. There is ambiguity: do we want to *get* that next ID or is it some method that's supposed to line up the next ID somehow?

I realize that you shouldn't just take guidelines from one library and apply it in the next, but I can't say I have seen it done differently so far and it does make a lot of sense to use the *get*-prefix.